# Tkinter Labels self update

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tkinter, linked-list, label

I have a linkedlist implemented in Python and for every node I need a label in a Tkinter window. The problem I have is that I don't know how to update the label when the corresponding node data changes.

currently I have this code for the window that displays all the nodes and the data within the nodes in its default "no data" state.

```
    def interface(self):
        Window = Tk()
        Row = 0
        current_node = self.get_top_of_list()
        while current_node is not None:
            Label(Window, text = current_node).grid(row = Row, column = 0)
            Label(Window, text = current_node.data).grid(row = Row, column = 1)       
            current_node = current_node.next_node
            Row +=1
        mainloop()
```

Comment: `Label` changes text automatically if it uses `StringVar` with `textvariable=` and you change text in `StringVar`. You could keep `Label` or `StringVar` inside node and node could change it when you change value in node. Linkedlist can't update labels automatically - you have to write function for it.

Comment: BTW: see [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Node could be "subject" (`Observable`) and `Label` or `StringVar` could be "observer" (`Observer`).

Comment: Other method is to use `root.after` to execute function which will get all data from nodes and updates Labels.

Comment: Thank you for your help, could you make an answer for your suggestions?

Comment: @JoeBlogs What exactly do you want label to show? data or next node or something else, for each node?

Comment: The Node objects will stay identical, only the contents (data) will change, so the current_node.data is the label i want to be updated. For every node, if two people join the server, two labels need to be updated e.g.

Answer (score 1):

As [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) also points out in the comment, Label widget will show its `textvariable` at all times, so you can modify the object that is assigned to `textvariable`, without referencing the label object again.

I'd add an attribute, `dataLabel` which later will hold my variable class object.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = None
        self.dataLabel = None
```

then assign that variable class object, `self.dataLabel` to my label's `textvariable` in my `interface` method:

```
def interface(self):
    Window = Tk()
    Row = 0
    current_node = self.get_top_of_list()
    while current_node is not None:
        current_node.dataLabel = StringVar()  #assuming from Window tkinter is imported as wildcard
        current.node.dataLabel.set(current_node.data)
        Label(Window, textvariable = current_node.dataLabel).grid(row = Row, column = 0)

        current_node = current_node.next_node
        Row +=1
    mainloop()
```

A similar object can be created for `next_node` attribute as well.

Comment: tkinter in tkinter.StringVar() isn't recognized because tkinter isn't initialized. Is having StringVar here correct?

Comment: @JoeBlogs No, it's incorrect. It needs to come after `Tk()`

Answer (score 0):

`Label` changes text automatically if it uses `StringVar` with `textvariable=` in `Label` and you change text in `StringVar`.

Linkedlist can't update labels automatically - you have to write function for it.

You could keep access to `Label` or `StringVar` inside node and node could change value in `Label` or `StringVar` when you change value in node.

See [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). `Node` could be "subject" (`class Observable`) and `Label` or `StringVar` could be "observer" (`class Observer`)

BTW: `StringVar`/`IntVar`/`otherVar` use pattern Observer. `StringVar` is "subject" and you can use `StringVar.trace()` to assign function to `StringVar` (it will be "observer") and `StringVar` will execute this function automatically when you change value in `StringVar`.

More on effbot.org: [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

---

Other method is to use `root.after` to execute function which will get all data from nodes and updates `Labels`

Simple example which use `after()` to display current time

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime

# --- functions ---

def update_time():
    # get current date & time as text
    current = datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d  %H:%M:%S')

    # update label with current date and time
    label['text'] = current

    # run update_time again after 1000ms (1s)
    root.after(1000, update_time)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

# create Label without text - update_time will set text
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

# run update_time first time
update_time()

root.mainloop()
```